# Как получить вчерашнюю дату для построения запроса в HealthKit:

Tags: swift, дата

Всем привет! Делаю фитнес-приложение, в котором получаю данные из `HealthKit`.

Есть такой вот запрос для получения данных -

```
let now = Date()
let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)

let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: date, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)
```

В нем я получаю данные по шагам за сегодняшний день.

Как получить данные за вчерашний, позавчерашний день? 
К примеру, нужно получить дату с 00:00, заканчивая этой же датой в 23:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отнимите от дат `60*60*24` секунд (сутки):

```
    let now = Date() // сегодня
    let date0 = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now) // 00:00:00 сегодня
    let date1 = date0 - (60*60*24) // 00:00:00 вчера
    let date2 = date1 + (60*60*24) - 1 // 23:59:59 вчера
    print(date0, date1, date2)
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/290411)

Comment: Дополнил ответ формулой.

Comment: Спасибо! А как получить позавчерашний день?

Comment: - (60*60*24)*N, где N число дней назад

Answer (score 0):

```
let today = Date()
let yestoday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day,
                                 value: -1,
                                 to: today)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.